# Image files not loading in Apache Linux Fedora 17. 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, lamp

Images are not loading in my server, This is the error I am getting

> Forbidden 
>   You don't have permission to access  PATH/abc.png on this server

I can access the images folder and all the images are listed but couldn't access it using url. There is no issue with **Permission** I have tried all permission levels including **777**.

Upon research I found the issue may be with the apache config file. This is how a part of **httpd.conf** looks like

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And there are no Aliases set for images. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what your apache error_log file says?

Comment: @NikhilSupekar - Permission denied: file permissions deny server access

Comment: @vishnu check if **path** is reachable under documentroot and folder has chmod 777 to ...

Comment: @donald123 Yes it is reachable. This is happening only for image files, I guess. I can access a text file in the same path

Comment: have you any restrictions set by <file> in your httpd.conf, vhost.conf, .htaccess or any other config file?

Comment: @vishnu is SELinux enalbed on your machine?

Comment: @donald123 - I am not much aware of this configurations. There is no <file> in httpd.conf and no .htaccess file in the project root

Comment: @NikhilSupekar - Yes, SELinux is enabled

Comment: in that case run `chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/images/directory` and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: @NikhilSupekar - Thanks a lot. Now the image is coming up. Could you please explain this as an answer, why this happened and what this command does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your httpd.conf seems all right and you have also tried to access files by giving permissions 777. But still you are unable to access your files.

This means that something else is denying the access. And this behavior is similar to SELinux Access Control.

So, [relabeling files](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux/#head-0f6390ddacfab39ee973ed8018a32212c2a02199) using chcon will solve this permission problem.

```
chcon -Rht httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/images/directory
```

CentOS wiki has a good explanation on [SELinux Access Control](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux/#head-4f1e4e4307ab4e76c81ae5fbebc24a907b24fd92)